# Odd particle behavior on hook animated curve

Tags: animation, particles, bezier-curves, hook-modifier

While working on a particle system, I've come across a problem where the particles are doing a spiral motion at a point near the end of the curve they travel along. Here are some gifs of the problem.

Without animating the hooks https://i.imgur.com/OdTrnSq.gif

When the hooks are animated: https://i.imgur.com/Sdi5e0E.gif

I'm really unsure why this is happening. The normals on the curve are all pointing the right way and none of it has any twist. What could be going on?

[image]